# How to launch multiple instance of an app on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, package, py2app

I had developed an app using py2app. Used python 2.7 on mac osx 10.9
When I launch the app(by clicking on any file), it starts performing the required action of opening file through default file opener and then monitoring the file changes.
I am passing **filename as argument** in the python code.
But app is not able to open multiple files at a time. I found issue with py2app as [py2app issue](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issue/136/how-to-initiate-multiple-instance-of-an) 
So, is there any other way to **convert python code into an app, so that multiple instance(process) can be generated of an app**

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the same question as [Launch multiple process of an app on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921549/launch-multiple-process-of-an-app-on-mac-osx).

The only workaround for the explanation in that question I can come up with is to split your application into two parts: a wrapper script that will be the main application, and the real script that's used as an "--extra-scripts". The wrapper script would forward the arguments to the real script and exit, something like:

```
 # wrapper.py
 import os, subprocess, sys
 appdir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
 subprocess.Popen([
      os.path.join(appdir, "real-script")] + sys.argv[1:])
 sys.exit(0)
```

And in setup.py:

```
setup(
    name="MyApp",
    app=["wrapper.py"],
    options=dict(py2app=(extra_scripts=["real-script.py"])))
```

(All of code was typed into the answer without testing, there might be some bugs left)